# Why can't I edit 2 separate meshes at once in edit mode in Blender 4

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices

I can't select 2 meshes (not joined) and go into edit mode and edit them together anymore in Blender 4. This was something Blender added several versions ago and now it seems to be gone. Is there something I need to enable now?

Comment: Seems to work for me with Blender 4.1.0. What version are you using ?

Comment: it works in 4.1 but of course for example you still can't bridge 2 faces that are from 2 different objects

Comment: I tried it in the two newest versions of Blender: 4.0.2 and 4.1.0. In each case editing multiple meshes worked perfectly.

Comment: Using 4.0.0. I'll try a newer version. I'm not doing bridge loops, just editing 2 meshes that have similar boundaries.

Comment: Where is the checkmark to accept answer?

Comment: @GlenP: these are all just comments. The checkmark is only available in answers.